# jMeter test on site using cloudflare

Tags: server, jmeter

I'm using jMeter to load test my server.

THe problem is my site is using cloudflare always use https. And I want to try it this way, so I can know exactly how my server and cloudflare can handle it.

I've tried to set the `protocol` to HTTPS still no luck. It keep return me

`Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: internal_error`

If I disabled the cloudflare, jMeter works like charm.

What should I do to make it work using cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter does work with HTTPS using HTTP sampler at least:
[image: HTTPS Exchange Example]
So, it seems like the reason is not in Jmeter. Could you please share a bit more info about your test scenario? Which samplers do you use?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with cloudfare, but that's what I got from the website: "We also block threats and limit abusive bots and crawlers from wasting your bandwidth and server resources". So, check your User-Agent header. Your requests can be blocked as potential bot activity. Just try to rewrite them (HTTP Sampler has appropriate option or just do it manually by HTTP Header Manager). And share the exchange flow if it's possible (I suggest you to force all Jmeter traffic through Fiddler 2 proxy or any analogue that can decode HTTPS traffic too).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your information about this. will check fiddler 2. and will reply soon